# Item image not shown when using a CollectionViewSource in a Windows Store app

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I've created a Windows Store app based on the Grid App XAML template in Visual Studio. It binds a `GridView` to a collection containing groups where each group contains items where each item contains some meta-data and an image. A `CollectionViewSource` is used for displaying the items within the groups in the grid view. This all works fine. I then added a button for adding a new item and when clicked the item with its meta-data is displayed but **not** the image. Click event-handler:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SampleDataGroup sampleDataGroup = SampleDataSource.GetGroup("Group-1");
    var sampleDataItem = new SampleDataItem("uniq", "Title", "Subtitle", "c:/users/christian/pictures/my_image.jpg", "Description", "Content", sampleDataGroup);
    sampleDataGroup.Items.Add(sampleDataItem);
}
```

However, if the image is read from the projects' Assets folder and not from the Pictures folder, it works as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have direct access to the file system in a Win8 app, so your image path (c:/users/christian/pictures/my_image.jpg) will fail to load the image in XAML.

Your best bet would be to code your class with an ImageSource, and load that in C# when your image file name changes.

[See here for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235026/metro-windows-8-c-xaml-how-to-find-valid-uris-to-pictures-stored-in-the-docu).

Comment: Thanks, I tried out the suggestion given [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithcsharp/thread/645cd100-88e3-4095-a5bf-2b078d65228c) which worked. I guess it's about the same as the example you linked to.

Answer (score 1):

As ZombieSheep (LOL) mentioned you cannot access the filesystem like that. Add the image to (for example) an Assets folder in your projects and reference it like so: (image called boot.jpg, element in View for Image called MyImage). When working with collectionviewsource it's the same, just set the correct path (ms-appx:/// or use this.UriBase, or define a static readonly property that holds the uri base string).

Hope this helps :)

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        SetImage();
    }

    private static readonly Uri _baseUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///");

    void SetImage()
    {
        MyImage.UriSource = new Uri(this.BaseUri, "Assets/boot.jpg");
        //MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/boot.jpg"));
        //MyImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(_baseUri,"/Assets/boot.jpg"));
    }
}
```

You have to set a new BitmapImage OR define the BitmapImage in the view and just set the Uri :)

Comment: Thanks, that would help in a testing scenario.